# Why lightningsnapin/minimized lwc is not working?

Tags: lightning-web-components, liveagent

I am trying to override default minimized livechat window with LWC, but it still renders default one. I am putting that LWC component on Chat Settings Page next under 'Customize with Lightning Components'. I am overriding 'Minimized' standard component. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

here is the code HTML:

```html
<template>  
     <button class="minimizedContainer" onclick={handleClick}>
        <div class="messageContent">{message}</div>
    </button>   
</template>
```

here is the code JS:

```javascript
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { assignHandler, maximize } from 'lightningsnapin/minimized';

export default class CustomMinimized extends LightningElement {
    @track message;

    constructor() {
        super();

        // Assign handler per event.
        assignHandler("prechatState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("offlineSupportState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("waitingState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("queueUpdate", this.setMinimizedQueuePosition.bind(this));
        assignHandler("waitingEndedState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("chatState", this.setMinimizedChatState.bind(this));
        assignHandler("chatTimeoutUpdate", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("chatUnreadMessage", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("chatTransferringState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("chatEndedState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("reconnectingState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
        assignHandler("postchatState", this.setMinimizedMessage.bind(this));
    }

    /**
     * Handler for when the minimized container is clicked.
     */
    handleClick() {
        maximize();
    }

    /**
     * Update the contents of the minimized message.
     *
     * @param {String} eventData - Contains a label attribute of the text to display.
     */
    setMinimizedMessage(eventData) {
        this.message = eventData.label;
    }

    /**
     * Update the contents of the minimized message with queue position label and value.
     *
     * @param {Object} eventData - Contains a label and a queue position attribute.
     */
    setMinimizedQueuePosition(eventData) {
        this.message = eventData.label;
        // For queue position = 0, the label will be "You're next!"
        if (eventData.queuePosition) {
            this.message += " " + eventData.queuePosition;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update the contents of the minimized message with name of the agent.
     *
     * @param {Object} eventData - Contains an agent name attribute.
     */
    setMinimizedChatState(eventData) {
        this.message = eventData.agentName;
    }
}
```

here is the CSS:

```css
.minimizedContainer {
    background-color: purple;
    position: fixed;
    left: auto;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 12em;
    max-width: 14em;
    height: 46px;
    width: 192px;
    max-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    pointer-events: all;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(0, 112, 210);
    font-size: 16px;
}

.minimizedContainer:focus,
.minimizedContainer:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: underline;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgb(0, 95, 178);
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.messageContent {
    padding: 0 8px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

here is XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
    <target>lightningSnapin__Minimized</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Please include details/code snippet on how you are trying to override default minimized livechat window with LWC?

Comment: @Swetha updated, check please

Comment: Could you please show the (in this context) most important part of your LWC config too: The configuration file (.js-meta.xml)?! Have you specified `<target>lightningSnapin__Minimized</target>`?

Comment: @FelixvanHove updated, please check

Comment: Once I had a similar issue. Minimized chat was loaded after open and minimizing, not at the beginning. Try to open chat and minimize.

Comment: @PiotrGajek I was thinking maybe lwc does not work because I am testing chat in VF preview page?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. Piotr's comment was correct, I had to minimize the chat and then my custom component took over.
I haven't found a way to load the custom component on chat load - as per the description, it seems like the custom is only available when minimizing after initial load... Even after close, the default component takes over.

[image: Description in Embedded Deployment]